# Как сделать авторизацию на сайте через Google?

Tags: wordpress, авторизация

Как сделать такую же авторизацию?
Заходишь на сайт, он видит что ты авторизован на сайте google.ru и предлагает войти на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Где YOUR_CLIENT_ID это уникальный сгенерированный ключ в гугл консоли разработчика
https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=RU

А лучше почитайте про Google API

Comment: а данные юзера после авторизации попадут в список пользователей вордпресс?

Comment: и он станет авторизованным на сайте?

Comment: Вы получаете данные о пользователе через переменную profile. А дальше манипулируете с функционалом wordpress.
Можете посмотреть этот плагин
https://wordpress.org/plugins/sign-in-with-google/

Comment: Он будет видеть что пользователь зашёл на сайт автор зованный на сайте гугла и предложит авторизоваться? Или просто кнопка Авторизации появится В форме входа?

Comment: На том сайте что я указал я не пытаюсь войти но сайт определил что я автор Хованский в гугле и предлагает авторизоваться на их сайте под этим же логином.

Comment: 1. На каком сайте, на который Вы указали?
2. Для такой авторизации, в любом случае, нужно взаимодействовать с Google Console и сайт должен быть с сертификатом SSL (https://) что бы позволить пользователю войти с помощью учётной записи Google.

Comment: Так и есть. Сайт мой allremont59.ru